# how to add custom options to grouped products with customization..?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, jquery

I have multiple simple product. and I have added this simple product in grouped product. 
As I know Magento allows only the simple product with custom option. Now I want to add the custom option to each product in grouped product.
Please anyone knows about it How to add customization of it then help me. But without using paid extension..want With own functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop custom extension for achieve this functionality because by default Magento has no feasibility to display custom options of simple product or you can try below mentioned extension.i am using same it's working fine.
http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html

Comment: Ok.. thank you..